# Connection Error While Using Getting Media Of A Submission on Praw

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, reddit, praw

I was trying get the media of a submission that had a media as image using Praw. As I run the code I got two error that I could not solve:

```
prawcore.exceptions.RequestException: error with request ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))

ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

Although I also try to convert the byte code of the image to a PIL image and then to display it, the errors occur on a earlier stage, therefore I think that there is not connection between the error and PIL. I also thought that it was related to the minutely 100 API limit, but I only do one request in my code. I would be somewhat grateful if someone helped me to solve the issue.

The code:

```
client=praw.Reddit(
                client_id=os.getenv("client_id"),
                client_secret=os.getenv("client_secret"),
                username=os.getenv("UNAME"),
                password=os.getenv("password"),
                user_agent="bot info"
                )
sub:praw.reddit.Submission=client.submission(id="some id")

resp=client.get(sub.url) 
img=Image.open(BytesIO(resp.content)) 
img.show()
```

Note : The imports have been done on a previous part of the code

I expect seeing help to fix the Connection Error so that the image gets displayed when the code is run.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.